# Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate ui-test-support-0.3.23, because minitest-5.2. 3 conflicts with minitest (< 5.0) getting this error

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am trying to run my scripts with two gems
1. minitest reporter 
2. ui-test-support

I am also able to do a bundle install but when I try run my scripts I am getting an error

```
Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate ui-test-support-0.3.23, because minitest-5.2.
3 conflicts with minitest (< 5.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minitest 5.2.3 is not compatible with ui-test-support.

Follow these steps:

1. Check which versions on minitest and ui-test-support are installed with `gem list`
2. If minitest is greater than 5.x then we have a problem.
3. Run this command `jruby -S gem uninstall minitest`
4. Edit your `Gemfile` and lock version of minitest to **"<5"**
5. Now do a `jruby -S bundle install`
6. It will install a compatible version of minitest with ui-test-support.